# Proving if $|A|\ge 4 \vee |A|\le 2$ then $|A+A|\neq 4$ with direct, contradiction and contraposition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, sumset

> Prove if $|A|\ge 4 \vee |A|\le 2$ then $|A+A|\neq 4$. $A$ is some set and we define $A+B=\{a+b|a\in A, b\in B\}$, $A$ is some subset of the reals.

In a direct proof and proof by contradiction I'd have to check every case for $|A|=0,1,2,4$ right?

In a proof by contra position I'd have to show that if $|A+A|=4$ then $|A|=3$ but I'm getting a contradiction, suppose $A+A=\{a,b,c,d\}$ then

$a=m+m\\b=n+n\\c=l+l\\d=m+n$

But there are still two elements left: $n+l,m+l$. How could it be that a direct proof works but a contra position results in a contradiction?

Comment: That is not true. Suppose $A=\{2\}$, then $|A|=2\leq 2$ and $|A+A|=|\{4\}|=4$.

Comment: @GregordeCillia um the notation for $|A|$ means how many elements are in $A$ or its cardinality.

Comment: What is $+$ between two elements? This sets have some additional structure? (like being subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ for example)?

Comment: @OfirSchnabel it's a regular addition, no info is given about the sets but they can't be subsets of "advanced" sets, just the complex, reals, integers, rationals and naturals. I realize it's probably possible to define some field that it won't work in but it's not what they intended.

Comment: @kuhaku I think that $|A+A|$ is never $4$.

Comment: @OfirSchnabel so this question is actually a tautology?

Comment: If $A$ is a cyclic abelian group then $A+A=A$. So in that case $|A|\geq 4$ does not imply that $|A+A|\neq4$. The information "$A$ is some set" is not enough.

Comment: @kuhaku if $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then yes. $|A+A|\neq 4$.

Comment: @drhab I never heard of that group and they intended $A$ to be a subset of complex, reals, integers, rationals and naturals

Comment: @kuhaku Take $\{a,b,c\}\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b<c$. Then $\{a+a,a+b,b+b,b+c,c+c\}$ are all different.

Comment: @OfirSchnabel it looks like it's true for all of the subsets of the reals as well...

Comment: There's no contradiction. Your result is true and the statement is still true. What you are testing is if |A| = 3, then |A + A| = 4, which needn't be true.

Comment: In other words, you argument isn't valid because you assumed A + A to have 4 elements, then you assumed that these must be sums of just three elements in A, which needn't be the case. Why didn't you say: a = m + n; b = o + p; c = q + r; d = s + t? In fact, this is what you should do to reach that |A| = 3 (assuming that the proposition is really true, which I'm not quite sure of yet).

Comment: Ofir, your example is irrelevant. This is the inverse of the statement and not the contraposition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's easier to prove this directly. If |A| = 1, it's clear that |A + A| is not 4. If |A| = 2, then A + A can have at most 3 elements. If |A| = n > 4, then let the elements of A be:

a1, a2, ...., an

We know that a1, ..., a5 are distinct. So 2a1, 2a2, ..., 2a5 are distinct, but these are in the form ai + ai with ai in A; thus, A + A has at least 5 elements.

It remains to handle the case |A| = 4. For this, let A = {a1, a2, a3, a4}. It's easy to see |A + A| >= 4 because 2ai are distinct, for all i. Now if |A + A| = 4, then it must be that:

A + A = {2a1, 2a2, 2a3, 2a4}.

Now, work out a contradiction by forcing the existence of an additional element ak + at for some k and t between 1 and 4.

Comment: It's actually true for $|A|=3$ too so it's a tautology for all sets that aren't cyclic.

Answer (score 2):

The rules of the game are unclear.

You have to tell us the underlying (abelian) group of which $A$ is a subset. E.g., if $A={\mathbb Z}_2\oplus{\mathbb Z}_2$ is the four group then $|A|=4$ and $|A+A|=|A|=4$.